# How can I fix Zooming issue on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, browser, zooming

Website is built on wordpress with some customization, everytime I try to zoom out and in the layout becomes messy and needs to be refreshed every time for the layout to be fixed.

Tried it on different browsers but the issue remains!

Answer (score -2):

In your WordPress admin panel,
go to Appearance -> Customize.
Select the “Additional CSS” option from the sidebar.
Paste the above CSS code into the provided text box.
Save the changes.

Comment: Which code? will it solve the zooming  in and out issue affecting the layout ?